# how to go switch between more than tow view in swift

Tags: swift, view, switch-statement

I want to create an application. My app works with a server. In the first view the user sends phone number to the server. Server answers and I analyze the answer. When user is new go to newsier view to get a name and family etc. or is not new go to another view (this view fill with data receive from server).
How to choose the view ???

edite :i want when in text box 2 go to second view else go to third view

first view

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
@IBAction func segue(sender: UIButton) {

    if text.text == "2"{

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: self)
    }
    else{

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("third", sender: nil)
    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}
second view:

```
import UIKit
```

class SecondView: UIViewController {

}

and Story board:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mNAZ.png)

Comment: hi and welcome to SO, if you provide your code attempts so far then the community are going to be much more inclined to help that than 'give me code' without evidence of effort. That way they can help many more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose with [Segue Action](http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/).
First you must have a navigation controller on your current view.
Then.. You should create a segue and then identify it.

Last: You can going to new view with this code from your current view.

```
@IBAction func postButAction(sender: UIButton) {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("identify_name", sender: nil)
 }
```

UPDATE: First, are you sure about that you create a segue on storyboard between the views and identify it.

Second, if you sure you can follow this:

You must write this code inside your new view:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "identify_name" {
            self.viewDidLoad()
        }
}
```

Comment: 2016-07-22 14:41:15.406 segu[5724:318309] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'third'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: Are you add navigation controller to your main view? if you do, then push modal should work. check my update please.

Comment: thank thank thank thank alot , i khonw it but i forget thank .

Comment: You welcome :) If it worked, please mark answer as a resolved so other people can use it.